# Storing the result of an 'x.times do' loop in a different variable upon each completion?

Tags: ruby, loops

I have code that runs a 'do' loop a number of times set by a user input, then outputs the result of that loop.

I want to store each result in its own variable once each instance of the loop completes so I can use them later. Right now they're printed in the terminal and the program forgets them.

This is an example of the code I have so far:

```
input_num.times do
  loop_select = rand(1..4)
  loop_select = loop_select.round
  if loop_select == 1
    answer = answer.instance_eval{method.method.method}
    set_answer = answer
  elsif loop_select == 3
    answer = answer.instance_eval{method.method.method}
    set_answer = answer
  elsif loop_select == 2
    answer = answer.instance_eval{method.method.method}
    set_answer = answer
  elsif loop_select == 4
    answer = answer.instance_eval{method.method.method}
    set_answer = answer
  end
  set_answer = print_answer.html
  puts set_answer
end
```

I want `set_answer` to be something like `set_answer_1`, `set_answer_2`, etc. for each iteration of the loop, but I can't set this as a static number because the amount of times vary for each input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foo = 5 
output = foo.times.map do |i|
  "loop #{i}"
end
output # => ["loop 0", "loop 1", "loop 2", "loop 3", "loop 4"]
```

where `foo` is the input from the user.

Comment: This worked once I figured out the proper way to define the array in my scenario. Thank you!